# Curiously recurring template pattern constraints with Scala abstract types

Tags: scala, crtp, abstract-type

I have a Scala compiler error puzzle that I can't figure out. For reasons not given here, I need to declare my classes using the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). Some of my classes need to contain others as parameters. For example, a stripped down version of my code looks like this:

```
trait Container[C <: Container[C]] {
  def stuff: C
}

trait Aggregation {
  def fill(x: Double): Unit
}

class Counted extends Container[Counted] {
  def stuff = this
}

class Counting extends Container[Counting] with Aggregation {
  def stuff = this
  def fill(x: Double) { }
}

class Binned[V <: Container[V]](v: V) extends Container[Binned[V]] {
  def stuff = this
  def substuff = v
}

class Binning[V <: Container[V] with Aggregation](v: V) extends Container[Binning[V]] with Aggregation {
  def stuff = this
  def substuff = v
  def fill(x: Double) { }
}
```

The above works fine. Now I want to add an abstract type from each -ing to each -ed:

```
trait Container[C <: Container[C]] {
  type Ed <: Container[Ed]
  def stuff: C
}

trait Aggregation {
  def fill(x: Double): Unit
}

class Counted extends Container[Counted] {
  type Ed = Counted
  def stuff = this
}

class Counting extends Container[Counting] with Aggregation {
  type Ed = Counted
  def stuff = this
  def fill(x: Double) { }
}

class Binned[V <: Container[V]](v: V) extends Container[Binned[V]] {
  type Ed = Binned[V]
  def stuff = this
  def substuff = v
}

class Binning[V <: Container[V] with Aggregation](v: V) extends Container[Binning[V]] with Aggregation {
  type Ed = Binned[V#Ed]
  def stuff = this
  def substuff = v
  def fill(x: Double) { }
}
```

and the compiler has the nerve to tell me

```
<console>:34: error: type arguments [V#Ed] do not conform to class Binned's type parameter bounds [V <: Container[V]]
             type Ed = Binned[V#Ed]
```

when `Ed` is clearly `<: Container[Ed]` for all `Containers`.

Strictly speaking, type `Ed` is only needed on `Containers with Aggregation`, and if I move it there, I get the same error.

Does anybody know how I can state my intention to the compiler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Binning[V <: Container[V] with Aggregation](val v: V) extends Container[Binning[V]] with Aggregation {
  type Ed = Binned[v.Ed]
  def stuff = this
  def substuff = v
  def fill(x: Double) { }
}
```

works. But it does seem to me like your version should compile as well.

Comment: Thank you, awesome, fantastic! I'm smacking myself on the forehead for such an obvious solution, though I agree that it seems like both should work.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `val` in the argument list becomes necessary, since we can't refer to `v.Ed` when `v` is private. In my use-case, I do want `v` to be public, so all is well.

Comment: I suggest asking why `V#Ed` doesn't compile in the scala-user mailing list if you don't get an answer on this.